# Is it right preposition in the sentence?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

sentence:

> The man has senseless ability **to** low temperature *(he feels no discomfit when his body exposed to low temperature)*

question:

> Should I use 'to' or 'of' preposition in this sentence?

Comment: "The man is *insensitive to* low temperatures." perhaps. Your example does not describe an ability.

Answer (score 2):

No, instead you would say the person had a "high tolerance for cold temperatures", or "did not feel the cold".

"Senseless ability" is not a natural English expression (although it could be used figuratively in a different context).